# Accesing a variable inside a class, inside another class, inside a namespace

Tags: c#, class, unity-game-engine, variables, namespaces

I'm a rookie, starting on the world of code, i'm a videogame developer actually in its first internship.

My question is this one, i have a variable inside a class, inside another class, inside a namespace, and i need to acces that variable from a different script.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Events;
using System.Collections.Generic;
#if UNITY_EDITOR
using UnityEditor;
#endif

namespace PaintIn3D
{
    
    [RequireComponent(typeof(Renderer))]
    [RequireComponent(typeof(P3dPaintable))]
    [HelpURL(P3dHelper.HelpUrlPrefix + "P3dPaintableTexture")]
    [AddComponentMenu(P3dHelper.ComponentMenuPrefix + "Paintable Texture")]
    public class P3dPaintableTexture : P3dLinkedBehaviour<P3dPaintableTexture>
    {
        public enum StateType
        {
            None,
            FullTextureCopy,
            LocalCommandCopy
        }

        public enum MipType
        {
            Auto,
            ForceOn,
            ForceOff
        }

        [System.Serializable] public class PaintableTextureEvent : UnityEvent<P3dPaintableTexture> {}

        
        public P3dSlot Slot { set { slot = value; } get { return slot; } } [SerializeField] private P3dSlot slot = new P3dSlot(0, "_MainTex");

        
        public P3dChannel Channel { set { channel = value; } get { return channel; } } [SerializeField] private P3dChannel channel;

        
        public P3dGroup Group { set { group = value; } get { return group; } } [SerializeField] private P3dGroup group;

        
        public StateType State { set { state = value; } get { return state; } } [SerializeField] private StateType state;

        
        public int StateLimit { set { stateLimit = value; } get { return stateLimit; } } [SerializeField] private int stateLimit;

        
        public string SaveName { set { saveName = value; } get { return saveName; } } [SerializeField] private string saveName;

        
        public string ShaderKeyword { set { shaderKeyword = value; } get { return shaderKeyword; } } [SerializeField] private string shaderKeyword;

    
        public RenderTextureFormat Format { set { format = value; } get { return format; } } [SerializeField] private RenderTextureFormat format;

    
        public MipType MipMaps { set { mipMaps = value; } get { return mipMaps; } } [SerializeField] private MipType mipMaps;

    
        public int Width { set { width = value; } get { return width; } } [SerializeField] private int width = 512;

    
        public int Height { set { height = value; } get { return height; } } [SerializeField] private int height = 512;

    
        public Color Color { set { color = value; } get { return color; } } [SerializeField] private Color color = Color.white;

    
        public Texture Texture { set { texture = value; } get { return texture; } } [SerializeField] private Texture texture;


        public event System.Action<P3dCommand> OnAddCommand;

    
        public event System.Action<bool> OnModified;
    }
}
```

There is a lot more content on the second class but i dont think is relevant (<- noob opinion).

I need to acces the Texture variable so the user of the app can insert a Texture through a file explorer, but i dont know how to do that.

I tried this:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEditor;
using SmartDLL;
using System.IO;
using PaintIn3D;


public class Explorer2 : MonoBehaviour
{
    public P3dPaintableTexture newTexture;
    /*public GameObject eImage;*/
    public Button openExplorerButton;
    private bool readImage = false;

    public SmartFileExplorer fileExplorer = new SmartFileExplorer();

    void OnEnable()
    {
        openExplorerButton.onClick.AddListener(delegate { ShowExplorer(); });
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (fileExplorer.resultOK && readImage)
        {
            OpenImage(fileExplorer.fileName);
            readImage = false;
        }
    }

    void ShowExplorer()
    {
        string initialDir = @"C:\";
        bool restoreDir = true;
        string title = "Open a Image File";
        string defExt = "png";
        string filter = "txt files (*.png)|*.png";
        fileExplorer.OpenExplorer(initialDir, restoreDir, title, defExt, filter);
        readImage = true;
    }



    void OpenImage(string path)
    {
        WWW www = new WWW("file:///" + path);
        newTexture.Texture = www.texture;     /* <----- This Line */
        
    }
}
```

But that shows me this result:

Inspector

[image: Inspector]

On the left of this image, is how the texture is shown when i drag it directly through the inspector, on the right is how its shown when i use the signaled line of code on the files explorer to acces the variable, its like it went half through but the texture image is not completely inside the variable, and the texture is not applied to the object.

Comment: You need to wait the download is completed to update it. Use coroutine for it or unitywebrequest.

Answer (score 0):

The downloaded texture just seems to have no name but referenced correctly otherwise the field would say `None(Texture)`.

You could just set one like e.g.

```
newTexture.name = "Oh now I have a name";
```

However, **you are not waiting** until the download finished so you are trying to use a texture before it is fully downloaded.

I don't see in your code how this texture should be applied to anything else.

---

In general note that `WWW` is by long marked as **obsolete**, you should rather use [`UnityWebRequestTexture.GetTexture`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequestTexture.GetTexture.html).

```
void OpenImage(string path)
{
    StartCoroutine(OpenImageRoutine(path));
}

private IEnumerator OpenImageRoutine(string path)
{
    using (var uwr = UnityWebRequestTexture.GetTexture("file:///" + path))
    {
        yield return uwr.SendWebRequest();

        if (uwr.isNetworkError || uwr.isHttpError)
        {
            Debug.Log(uwr.error);
        }
        else
        {
            // Get downloaded texture
            newTexture.Texture = DownloadHandlerTexture.GetContent(uwr);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The script with the variable is bigger than what i posted, thing that i thought could be very annoying to everyone so i omited eveything that wasnt the variables, but its a script on a quad, that, in game, applies the texture to the quad and let it be modificable (paintable).

The issue with the no name texture is that, it isnt applying to the quad, thing that doesnt happen with other textures loaded the same way ont he same app, but whose variables are just under a single class, so i have no problems accesing them.

Comment: About the tip with the www, thanks for the advice, i knew it was obsolete, but no one taught me how to replace it.

Comment: I dont understand the part of waiting for the texture to fully download, i'm using images on my hdd.

Comment: still you have to wait until they are fully loaded ... FileIO takes time. Please refer to the example in the link I provided it basically shows how to wait for the result of the Request ... it is basically the same for the `WWW` class: you have to `yield return` in a Coroutine until the loading is done and you can actually use the texture